# No input file specified и после обновления страницы 502 Bad gateway

Tags: php, phpstorm, mamp

Добрый день,возникла сегодня такая проблема, не запускается никакой скрипт даже `echo 'Hell world';`
Среда разработки PhpStorm  локальный сервер MAMP.
В логах апача даже ошибки нет,подскажите в чем может быть проблема?
Сначала выводило строку  No input file specified, а после ошибку 502 на все файлы

Comment: 1. при чём тут используемый ide? 2. раскройте связь между apache и nginx.

Comment: @alexander barakin в вопросах похожих на мой, первыми вопросами были какую IDE используете и стоял хэштеги nginx (возможно это не правильно) я просто еще начинающий и порой возникают такие ошибки.
Но т.к я ответа не нашел в сети, то задал свой вопрос

Comment: @OlegSavchuk - php-cgi установлен?